# Tukey HSD for categorical and continuous variables in R

Tags: r, anova, posthoc, tukey, factoring

I want to do a post-hoc test for a significant ANOVA I've done successfully.

I have 5 conditions (target_onset) across which I want to compare reaction times (key_resp.rt) in a df called data_clean. target_onset and key_resp.rt are columns.

This is how I did the ANOVA, which worked fine:

```
cond.aov <- aov(data_clean$target_onset ~ data_clean$key_resp.rt)
summary(cond.aov)
```

Next, I want to see what a post-hoc test says to find out which differences between the 5 conditions are significant.

I know that TukeyHSD only takes factors. So I factorized my columns of interest:

```
data_clean$target_onset <- factor(data_clean$target_onset)
data_clean$key_resp.rt <- factor(data_clean$key_resp.rt)

TukeyHSD(aov(data_clean$target_onset ~ data_clean$key_resp.rt))
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

> Error in class(y) <- oldClass(x) :    adding class "factor" to an
> invalid object In addition: Warning messages: 1: In model.response(mf,
> "numeric") :   using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be
> ignored 2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for
> factors

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** first time through I missed the fact you had the formula backwards as well!

You need to make `target_onset`  a factor **before** issuing the `aov` function.  You do **not** want to make `key_resp.rt` a factor at all.

So the sequence should be...

```r
data_clean$target_onset <- factor(data_clean$target_onset)

cond.aov <- aov(key_resp.rt ~ target_onset, data = data_clean)

summary(cond.aov)

TukeyHSD(cond.aov)
```

The dependent variable (the response time goes on the left of the tilde and the independent grouping variable to the right.

If you don't make the condition/grouping variable a `factor` `aov` which actually do an `lm` using the numbers you have in the grouping column you can see that reflected in the degrees of freedom for the `cond.aov`.

As long as you already have an `aov` object might as well make the call to `TukeyHSD` as simple as possible

Comment: If you're new to `r` you may also want to investigate some of the packages like `ggstatsplot` that will do everything for you including plotting the results nicely.